# JavaFX observer pattern to enable button

Tags: java, javafx

In a small JavaFX application I would like to implement a simple validation check.
One button should be enabled ONLY if two boolean variables are true, one combobox has an selected item and at least one checkbox (out of five) is selected.

Imho as a newbie I think that should be implemented with the observer pattern. My question: How can the button (aka observer) be notified about the correct values/states of the components (aka subjects) to get enabled?

Thanks.

Comment: [Bind](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107) the [disable](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#disableProperty) property using the _fluent API_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bindings for this. You can learn more about bindings, and properties, by reading the [Using JavaFX Properties and Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) article. I also recommend studying the [`javafx.beans.binding`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/package-summary.html) API. The `Bindings` class offers many static utilities for binding. And the `XXXExpression` classes offer the fluent binding API if you prefer that.

Note that all standard property *classes* provided in the [`javafx.beans.property`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/package-summary.html) package inherit from their corresponding "expression class". For example, a `BooleanProperty` inherits from `BooleanExpression`. That means you can use the fluent API with the properties of the various nodes/controls provided by JavaFX.

Here is an example with one `ComboBox`, five `CheckBox`es, and a `Button`. The button will be disabled if the combo box has no item selected or if none of the check boxes are selected. This is accomplished via the fluent API. The example does not include your "two boolean variables", as I don't know exactly what you mean by that; however, if you make the type of those two variables `BooleanProperty`, or at the very least `ObservableValue<Boolean>`, then you should be able to adapt the code to fit your needs relatively easily.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanExpression;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(Main.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var comboBox = createComboBox();
    var checkBoxes = createCheckBoxes();
    var button = createButton();

    // Use bindings to disable the button when appropriate
    var noItemSelected = comboBox.valueProperty().isNull();
    var noCheckBoxesSelected =
        checkBoxes.stream()
            .map(box -> box.selectedProperty().not()) // not selected
            .reduce(BooleanExpression::and) // *all* not selected
            .orElseThrow();
    // If *either* the combo box has no item selected, or none of the check
    // boxes are selected, then disable the button.
    button.disableProperty().bind(noItemSelected.or(noCheckBoxesSelected));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createGridPane(comboBox, checkBoxes, button)));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private GridPane createGridPane(
      ComboBox<String> comboBox, List<CheckBox> checkBoxes, Button button) {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(30));
    grid.setHgap(20);
    grid.setVgap(10);

    grid.add(comboBox, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.size(); i++) {
      grid.add(checkBoxes.get(i), 1, i);
    }
    grid.add(button, 1, checkBoxes.size());

    return grid;
  }

  private ComboBox<String> createComboBox() {
    var comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      comboBox.getItems().add("Item " + i);
    }
    return comboBox;
  }

  private List<CheckBox> createCheckBoxes() {
    var checkBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>(5);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      checkBoxes.add(new CheckBox("Check " + i));
    }
    return checkBoxes;
  }

  private Button createButton() {
    var button = new Button("Action...");
    button.setOnAction(
        e -> {
          e.consume();
          System.out.println("ACTION!");
        });
    return button;
  }
}
```